# adding and deleting from two tables at one time?

Tags: php, mysql

how to delete and add in same query but in two different tables, one need to add data and in the other one data should be deleted  how to do this any help ?

Please help me out with an example:

```
function addConfirmemil($data){
  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `meet_ups_list` WHERE id=".$data." LIMIT 1 inner join `contact_list` on a = d; INSERT INTO `contact_list` (".array2keys($data).",`uid`) VALUES (".array2values($data).",'".$_SESSION['uid']."')");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You should rather wrap those query in a stored procedure and call that SP from your PHP code instead